# How to use multiset in flink?

Tags: apache-flink

I use **collect()** function in flink sql, and the return type is **multiset**.
However, common functions such as **cardinality, char_length, multiset[item]** all cannot use for multiset.
How can I get the element in multiset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The support for multisets is limited at the moment. However, you can define you own [user-defined functions](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/table/functions/udfs/) to deal with them. Using a `@DataTypeHint("MULTISET<X>")` can be used whereever a `Map<X, Integer>` can be used.

Comment: OK. Thank you! I will try to define udf.